# Intersection of lines in maple

Tags: math, maple

How do I find the intersection of two lines in maple when plotted as follows:

```
a:=line([1,-1,-1],[0,0,1]):
b:=line([1,1,1],[0,-1,0]):
```

I attempted to use the intersection command but it returned this:

```
intersection(CURVES([[1., -1., -1.], [0., 0., 1.]]), CURVES([[1., 1., 1.], [0., -1., 0.]]))
```

Thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line's first argument is the name of the line you are symbolically defining.

Instead of using

```
a:=line([1,-1,-1],[0,0,1]):
b:=line([1,1,1],[0,-1,0]):
```

Try the following instead:

```
with(geom3d): 
point(p1,[1,-1,-1]):
point(p2,[0,0,1]):
point(p3,[1,1,1]):
point(p4,[0,-1,0]):
line(l1,[p1, p2]):
line(l2,[p3, p4]):
intersection(P,l1,l2):
coordinates(P)
```

See the help on [intersection](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=geom3d/intersection) and [line](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=geom3d%2Fline) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks very much (sorry I can't up vote your answer, when I have the required reputation I will)